# PHP Google People API - Simple email request failing

Tags: php, api, oauth

Thank you everyone for your time.

I've spent all day on this although, wasn't able to find a good example and answer, so I thought it may be relevant for the community.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('Google/src/Google/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxxx");
$client->setClientId('xxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxx')
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxxx');
$client->addScope('profile');
$client->addScope('email');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');

if (isset($_GET['oauth'])) {
    // Start auth flow by redirecting to Google's auth server
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // Receive auth code from Google, exchange it for an access token, and redirect to your base URL
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else if ($_SESSION['access_token']) {
    // You have an access token; use it to call the People API
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_People($client);
    $optParams = array('pageSize' => 10);

    // TODO: Use service object to request People data
    $results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);

} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/?oauth';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Upon executing the script I simply get a blank white page, if I comment out $results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams) the script then works.

It looks like it loads the API properly and authenticates with Oauth and the token session variables are set; although when uncommented it is simply a white screen so I think the problem is retrieving data from the Google People API.

I'm trying to download a list of each users contacts (including name & email) to share a link with via email; after clicking a 'Login with Google' button.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Thank you, that's actually a big help! After setting those, I've cleaned up a few things although am now presented with:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.' in /home/cat8806/public_html/Google/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:249

Comment: Stack trace: #0 /home/cat8806/public_html/Google/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(217): Google_Auth_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1 /home/cat8806/public_html/Google/src/Google/Service/People.php(258): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #2 /home/cat8806/public_html/inviteOthers.php(30):
Google_Service_People_PeopleConnections_Resource->listPeopleConnections('people/me', Array) #3 /home/cat8806/public_html/index.php(22): include('/home/cat8806/p...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/cat8806/public_html/Google/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php on line 249

Comment: The problem is solved, I just unset the previously set session variables and the function came to life!  For the purposes of this function I've unset the Google session variables after the data is retrieved, as it's purely just to retrieve contacts. I now have a Google people object that contains user data, just have to figure out what to do with it! :s haha thank you for your help.

Comment: I spent more than a day on this, I finally got it working as a drop-in replacement for my ageing Google code, and some of what I learned along the way is:
1. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$redirect_uri` and `$client->setRedirectUri` should all point back to _this_ script.
2. One way to "request people data" would be `$result = $service->people->get('people/me');`
3. the OP's solution to the access-token expiry problem works here.

Comment: Since the redirect URL is always the same (on my set up), I actually just hard coded it and luckily didn't have any issues with the redirect. I'll post my full solution below shortly, so that everyone else can see what I did... plus, more sample code is always helpful for people. I finally just figured out how to get the Outlook.com API working... a little easier, but it helps to get your head around the Oauth process. Feel like I've learnt a bit in this process. Thanks for your help and sharing.